# Couldn't get last insert identifier - Doctrine with mysql views

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have one table and one view (create view as select * from table). I am using php, mysql and doctrine 1.2 ORM.

If I insert data in table everything works as expected but when I try to insert data into view I get the following error:

```
Couldn't get last insert identifier.
```

Any idea how to fix this? (I really need to use views, so inserting into main table would not be OK)

Whole error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with
>   message 'Couldn't get last insert
>   identifier.' in
>   C:\wamp\www\www\class\lib\doctrine_1.2\lib\Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php:941
>   Stack trace:
>   C:\wamp\www\bicikel-www\class\lib\doctrine_1.2\lib\Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php(636):
>   Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->_assignIdentifier(Object(Event))
>   C:\wamp\www\www\class\lib\doctrine_1.2\lib\Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php(566):
>   Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->processSingleInsert(Object(Event))
>   C:\wamp\www\www\class\lib\doctrine_1.2\lib\Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php(81):
>   Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->insert(Object(Event))
>   C:\wamp\www\www\class\lib\doctrine_1.2\lib\Doctrine\Record.php(1705):
>   Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->saveGraph(Object(Event))
>   C:\wamp\www\www\opravila\migajznami_spider.php(97):
>   Doctrine_Record->save() {main} thrown
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\www\class\lib\doctrine_1.2\lib\Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php
>   on line 941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated Doctrine files and now it works.

I changed file: Doctrine\Connection\UnitOfWork.php, line 936 I added some code in else block:

```
} else {
    $id = $record->$identifier;
    if(!$id){    // added
    $id = $this->conn->sequence->lastInsertId();    // added
    } // added
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you haven't primary key with autoincrement . Doctrine is looking for autoincrement property.